# Unequal chunk size definition in xr.open_mfdataset

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I have NetCDF files with each file containing 5 years of daily data. I am reading it as follows and want to define unequal chunk size so as to process each year's daily data at once. But unable to slice annual data from each chunk of 5 years of daily data. Following is what I have:

```
flist = ['f1_2016_2020.nc','f2_2021_2025.nc','f3_2026_2030.nc','f4_2031_2035.nc']
chunk = [366, 365, 365, 365, 366, 365, 365, 365, 366, 365, 365, 365, 366, 365, 365, 365, 366, 365, 365, 365]
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(flist, concat_dim='day', chunks=chunk)
```

Please suggest if possible to define chunk size equal to the number of days in each year as described above or if there is any other way to this.

Comment: Are you just trying to find a way to operate on each year independently within the same dataset?

Comment: Yes, I want to operate on each year independently to obtain conditional count

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misinterpreting what chunking is.  It's just the amount of data that is processed per batch by dask when computing in parallel.  It is not how you separate and organize data for analysis - there are many ways to do this with xarray and pandas.

This should demonstrate what you are looking for:

```
time = xr.DataArray(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2009-12-31', freq='D'))
da = xr.DataArray(np.random.random(len(time)), dims=['time'], coords=[time], name='Temp')
da.groupby('time.year').sum(dim='time')

<xarray.DataArray 'Temp' (year: 10)>
array([186.243399, 177.013772, 177.043625, 178.909328, 185.276436, 188.423565,
       175.852382, 180.455858, 182.747201, 183.260242])
Coordinates:
  * year     (year) int64 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
```

Those years have the appropriate leap days included and are parsed out with the `groupby()`function.  If you need to perform a custom function rather than `sum()` you can use the `.apply(func)` instead.

Comment: I've used `da.groupby` solution before but processing half million points over 3 decades of daily time records with this approach takes considerable time. I ended up splitting nc files to annual tiles and used `xr.open_mfdataset` which sets chunk size equal to number of days in each tile -- processed each year's daily data at once this way.

Comment: @Ibe I wasn't totally clear in my answer.  I use the `groupby()` method in conjunction with a large number files opened with `open_mfdataset()`.  My main point is that is not necessary to pass specific chunking - you would receive the same result if you set chunks to 100 or 365.